# NOT NULL constraint failed: community_comment.posts_id?

Tags: python, django

how can I fix this issue?
the page runs perfectly. when I do post the post. it posts but when I want to type the comment and send by 'GET' I get this error. so, how can I ignore this error this my first question?
- also, I need anyone to give me the best way to make a relationship between post and comment

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Article(models.Model):
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline


class Post(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    posts = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm


def index(request):
    # All questions
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'community/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_view(request):
    post_form = PostForm
    context = {'posted': post_form}

    # Create post
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_form = PostForm(request.GET)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            user_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            user_post.title = post_form.cleaned_data['title']
            user_post.question = post_form.cleaned_data['question']
            post = Post.objects.create(users=User.objects.get(username=request.user), title=user_post.title, question=user_post.question)
            post.save()
            return redirect('community:index')

    return render(request, 'community/post.html', context)


def answers(request, post_id):
    # Specific post
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    # Create comment
    comment_form = CommentForm
    context = {'posts': posts, 'comment_form': comment_form}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.GET)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.comment = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            user_comment.save()

    return render(request, 'community/answers.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'community'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('post/', views.post_view, name='post'),
    path('answers/<int:post_id>', views.answers, name='answers'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Post, Comment
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['users']


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['users', 'posts']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the `post`, or the `post_id` of the comment you created:

```
def answers(request, post_id):
    # Specific post
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    # Create comment
    comment_form = CommentForm
    context = {'posts': posts, 'comment_form': comment_form}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.GET)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post_id = post_id
            user_comment = comment_form.save()
    # …
```

That being said, the above view does not really respect the HTTP assumptions. A view that makes a GET request is *not* supposed to change entities, so if you want to create a comment, you need to do that through a POST request. Furthemore in order to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) a *successful* POST request should return a redirect response.

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post_id = post_id
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            user_comment.comment = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            user_comment.save()

Comment: I edit what you say and I did POST instead of GET and i get the same message error

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin: you do not need to set `user_comment.comment = ...`, this logic is normally done by a `ModelForm` itself.

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin: can you edit your question with the *full* traceback?